# CSS scale transition ease-out not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I've been wanting to do this scale transition on an icon on a blog. And the ease-in is working properly but not the ease-out... I read some stuff but none of them are about the scale transition so I've been having a hard time applying it to my case.. 
Hope you can help me thanks
Here's my code :

```css
#avatar {
margin:auto;
margin-top:15px;
width:50px;
height:50px;
border-radius:60px;
border:0px solid {color:Main icon background};
z-index:10;
}
 
#avatar img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
border-radius:100%;
}

#avatar img:hover{
-webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in;  
-ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5); /* Safari */
transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar"><img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/valentint/valentint1503/valentint150302008/37824182-examples-icon-internet-button-on-colored-background.jpg?ver=6"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated the snippet to include

```
#avatar img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

To make the ease-out transition effective.

```css
#avatar {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  border:0px solid {
    color: Main icon background
  }
  ;
  z-index:10;
}

#avatar img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#avatar img:hover {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
  /* Safari */
  transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}

#avatar img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar"><img src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/valentint/valentint1503/valentint150302008/37824182-examples-icon-internet-button-on-colored-background.jpg?ver=6"></div>
```