# I am trying to remove the space and the images that slide and ease out on the sides do not scale in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms, keyframe

I tried [CSS scale transition ease-out not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835462/css-scale-transition-ease-out-not-working), but the images do not scale yet.

An image is worth a thousand words. You will understanding easily the image. I also provide the snippet code box.

[image]

The 3 left images scale decreasing themselves and slide/ease from right to left and out and the 3 right images scale decreasing themselves and slide/ease from left to right and out.

Run the snippet box as you can see there is the space between a red image and the image do not scale. And the images are not aligned.

```css
.sliding-images
{
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sliding-images img
{
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  width: 12%;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(1)
{
  transform: scale(1.1)  translateX(270%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1)  translateX(270%);
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.15s ease-out both;
          animation: slide-left 0.15s ease-out both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(2)
{
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(178%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) translateX(178%);
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.10s ease-out both;
          animation: slide-left 0.10s ease-out both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(3)
{
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.5s ease-out both;
          animation: slide-left 0.5s ease-out both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(4)
{
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  z-index: 4;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(5)
{
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s ease-out both;
         animation: slide-right 0.5s ease-out both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(6)
{
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-178%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-178%);
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.10s ease-out both;
         animation: slide-right 0.10s ease-out both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(7)
{
  transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-270%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-270%);
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.15s ease-out both;
         animation: slide-right 0.15s ease-out both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slide-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
            transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
            transform: translateX(-100px);
  }
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slide-right 
 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
            transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-right 
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
            transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="sliding-images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/fdc34f/FEFEFE?text=1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/3e72ff/FEFEFE?text=2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/222222/FEFEFE?text=3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/fe7b7b/FEFEFE?text=4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/24d366/FEFEFE?text=5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/afd33c/FEFEFE?text=6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/41c8b8/FEFEFE?text=7">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to calculate exact `width` and `translateX` positions.

see edited code snipped.

```css
.sliding-images
{
position:absolute;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 70%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sliding-images img
{
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  width: calc(100%/7);
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(1)
{
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.15s ease-out both,scale11 0.1s both;
          animation: slide-left 0.15s ease-out both,scale11 0.1s both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(2)
{
  transform: scale(1.2) translateX(178%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) translateX(178%);
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.10s ease-out both,scale12 0.1s both;
          animation: slide-left 0.10s ease-out both,scale12 0.1s both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(3)
{
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform-origin: right;
  -webkit-transform-origin: right;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide-left 0.5s ease-out both,scale13 0.1s both;
          animation: slide-left 0.5s ease-out both,scale13 0.1s both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(4)
{
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  z-index: 4;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(5)
{
  transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3) translateX(-87%);
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.5s ease-out both,scale13 0.1s both;
         animation: slide-right 0.5s ease-out both,scale13 0.1s both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(6)
{
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.10s ease-out both,scale12 0.1s both;
         animation: slide-right 0.10s ease-out both,scale12 0.1s both;
}

.sliding-images img:nth-child(7)
{
  transform-origin: left;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right 0.15s ease-out both,scale11 0.1s both;
         animation: slide-right 0.15s ease-out both,scale11 0.1s both;
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slide-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100%/7));
            transform: translateX(calc(-100%/7));
  }
}

@keyframes slide-left {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(-100%/7));
            transform: translateX(calc(-100%/7));
  }
}

 @-webkit-keyframes slide-right 
 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100%/7));
            transform: translateX(calc(100%/7));
  }
}

@keyframes slide-right 
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(calc(100%/7));
            transform: translateX(calc(100%/7));
  }
}

@keyframes scale11 
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

@keyframes scale12 
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes scale13 
{
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-images">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/fdc34f/FEFEFE?text=1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/3e72ff/FEFEFE?text=2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/222222/FEFEFE?text=3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/fe7b7b/FEFEFE?text=4">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/24d366/FEFEFE?text=5">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/afd33c/FEFEFE?text=6">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/432x864/41c8b8/FEFEFE?text=7">
  </div>
```

Comment: It almost worked, but scaling the images did not work.

Comment: @GustavoReis cause your animation (`slide-right` and `slide-left`) set new `transform` to you element and `scale` will removed.

Comment: Would the solution be replace `scale` for `height` in each `nth-child`?

Comment: @GustavoReis as is see result. you must set animation for every scales with transforms.

Comment: I have just seen and understood, no need for `height` as the animation allows to set multiples keyfarmes. But the top part is cut, I am not sure if adding `padding-top: 10%` is bad. And `calc(100%/7)` means 0.14 which means 14%?

Comment: @GustavoReis see my update answer. i add `position:absolute` for images and `height` will not cut. copy snipped. it cant see in this snipped .

Comment: Ah, I got, thank you. But does `calc(100%/7)` means 0.14 which means 14%?

Comment: @GustavoReis your welcome.  means 14.2857... . cause your elements are 7. its better to divide to 7. but when you have scale you must a bit change for every image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205034/discussion-between-gustavo-reis-and-ttrasn).

Comment: the top part of this spreading card stack is still cut on ultra-wide monitors (2560x1080 and 3840x1080).